# Images embedded in pdf disappearing using pdf.js contributed by Mozilla

Tags: javascript, pdf, canvas, pdf.js, image-conversion

I am using this link https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html to upload a test pdf file.

[The test pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HdBWMvMcs7qpabhMmw_4rxPPi4oGSrII)

[image]

The image is lost when previewing with pdfjs.

[image]

A temporary solution is to convert the file itself, convert this pdf to jpg first, and then convert this jpg to pdf.

Is it possible that the font is Chinese traditional? and how can I solve it, or can it be implemented via little code? Thanks a million!

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Hi, Reza, thanks for your reply, please try pdfjs's demo, and its link https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/